# Is there a way to get pass .env varables to my app.json file?

Tags: php, heroku, environment-variables, config

I have deployed my app to heroku but I want to get my .json file(where I store my database information) to heroku's webserver without pushing my file to github(file is ignored). I got the recommendation to use .env file. Is it possible to pass the information from a .env file to a .json file or do I need do change my code in some way?

I have tried logging into heroku to add the file on the server but it doesn't work because when the app restarts the app it resets.

app.json

```
{
    "db": {
        "dsn": "mysql:host=adress;dbname=database;charset=utf8",
        "user": "user",
        "password": "pass" 
    }
}
```

Connection.php

```
<?php

namespace TwitterClone\Core;

use \PDO;
use TwitterClone\Core\Config;
use TwitterClone\Utils\Singleton;

class Connection extends Singleton
{
    public $handler;
    protected function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $config = Config::getInstance()->get('db');
            $this->handler = new PDO(
                $config['dsn'],
                $config['user'],
                $config['password']
            );
            $this->handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Config.php

```
<?php

namespace TwitterClone\Core;

use TwitterClone\Utils\Singleton;
use TwitterClone\Exceptions\NotFoundException;

/**
 * Singleton
 */
class Config extends Singleton
{
    private $data;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../config/app.json');
        $this->data = json_decode($json, true);
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        if (!isset($this->data[$key])) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Key $key not in config.");
        }
        return $this->data[$key];
    }
}
```

I want to push the file to be on heroku's server but not on github. or a way to get information to the app.json file without showing sensitive information.

Comment: You can't connect to a local database (one on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`) on Heroku because web dynos don't run database servers. `.env` files won't help you here, but they're just a method for setting environment variables. Which MySQL addon are you using to host your database? It should set an environment variable for you that you can use to connect.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It was just me that forgot that I had the local credentials after saving. It's the credentials for the remote database I want to push to heroku. 

I'm using the ClearDB addon for the database. I got the variables from there. I got it to work But I don't know if it's right way.

Comment: Okay, so there should be an [environment variable called `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#using-the-cleardb-database-url). Use that instead of your JSON file. Part of the Heroku model is that [configuration should come from the environment](https://12factor.net/config). (Alternatively, I think you'll find more granular `CLEARDB_` variables containing things like your host, port, user, and password. Feel free to use those if you prefer.)

Comment: What I did was creating a new php file and use that instead of the json file. It worked at least. this is what I did:

`<?php
$path = "config/credentials.php";
// check if credentials exist
if (file_exists($path)) {
    require_once('credentials.php');
}
return [
    'dsn' => getenv('DB_DSN'),
    'user' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
];`


Basically it checks if the file credentials exist and if it does it will use the local variables. If not it will use the variables from heroku. 

Is this a good way to do it?